# React.js render different header bars

Tags: reactjs, redux, header, components

I have a React component issue.

In a React app, I would like to display a different header bar for mobile devices and another header for laptop or desktop. I'm using material-ui headers. I have created two separate header components so how do I configure
them in the App.jsx main to display one header for mobile device and another header when the user is on a laptop?

```
const headerLaptop =() ={
return (
<div>header element</div>
);
};

const headerMobile =() ={
return (
<div>header element</div>
);
};

const App =() ={
return (
<div>headerMobile or headerLaptop</div>
);
};
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You can adapt this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Answer (score 0):

Ot you are using material-ui, you can use `withWidth`  [see doc and example here](https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/#withwidth--)